# How to apply new WFS-Filter features like intersect

Tags: qgis, wfs

I was pleasantly surprised to find very much enlarged filter support in QGIS-Dev (1.9.0_Master).

One application would be a WFS-Filter which combines $geometry and Intersect in order to load only the data from WFS which would be visible in the actual extent.

Something like this: 
intersects( $geometry, geomFromWKT( 'LINESTRING(765145.88 6274561.22, 776031.67 6284189.52)' ) )

Found that one in
http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/11/06/Spatial-operators-in-QGIS-expression

But the above mentioned statement is not a valid expression in the "Expression string builder".

What is the correct way to phrase it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The filter code you pasted appears correct, and in fact it works when I try it in QGIS 2.8.1.  If this still does not work for you, it may be a bug: you can make a free account on their bug tracker and report it there: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here when Googling for WFS filters in QGIS.

The QGIS version that I have been using (i.e. 2.14) supports the functionality requested by OP as a tick box named **"Only request features overlapping the current view extent"** and can be found in the **"Add WFS Layer from a Server"** pop up menu.

Any ideas on where to get more recent information on WFS filters used in